# Avoid opening a form view in edit mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I need to open a form view that will show an on-the-fly generated data consisting on several fields which are made by a sum of several records (i.e. If I'm on a client, it will show the sum of the debt of all the clients of the same area) and need to do this on the same window.

I'm trying to do it with a wizard since it won't be save into the database, but it keeps opening the view in edit mode (with the *save* and *discard* buttons).

How could I avoid opening the view in edit mode and also keep the breadcrumbs from the client view.

I tried settings the 'target' key in the action to current, new, etc.. but can't get it to work, also tried with flags, but couldn't manage it to work...

This is the action I am using:

```xml
    <act_window
        id="my_wizard_action"
        name="Consolidación"
        src_model="clientes.one.rate"
        res_model="my.wizard"
        view_mode="form"
        view_type="form"
        target="inline" />
```

And this is the view:

```xml
    <record id="my_wizard_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">my.wizard</field>
        <field name="model">my.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group>
                    <field name="area"/>
                    <field name="sum"/>
                </group>              
                <footer>
                    <button string="Close" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>    
    </record>
```

I expect to open a view not in the edit mode (avoiding save and discard buttons), and also maintaining the same breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can consider to use display field and onchange method.

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):

display_field = fields.Integer("sum",store=False)
@api.onchange("trigger_field")
    def _check(self):
        sum = 0
        self.env.cr.execute("select field from my_module")
        for row in self._cr.fetchall():
            sum += row[0]
        self.display_field = sum
```